# There was no endpoint listening at Bing Maps Web Services

Tags: wcf, web-services, bing-maps

I am trying to do a small app who will use Bing Maps Web Services. When I try to connect the server to get information, I get the error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."

What is the problem? Could my network proxy be the cause?

If that can help, the error occurs in line :

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchResponse = searchService.Search(searchRequest);
```

the .config file has the code in `<cliente>`:

```
<endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchService"
            contract="SearchService.ISearchService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchService" />
```

Comment: Since you are on a network with a proxy you would need to add a defaultProxy element where you specify your proxy address as specified here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a network with a proxy, you would need to add a defaultProxy element to your config where you specify your proxy address. More [information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx)

Comment: <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                </

Comment: </httpTransport>
    </binding>

The config file has this, isn´t right ?

Comment: The useDefaultProxy setting is by default true indicating to use the machinewide proxy settings rather than using user specific settings and in your case the proxy usage might be a user setting.